Classes uses the same properties
I have a simple piece of code. In it I make 2 animals a cat and a spider. They have a difference number of legs and eyes. I just want to print these data.
class Legs:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount  

    def legsInfo(self):
        return f"{self.amount} legs"


class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount  

    def eyesInfo(self):
        return f"{self.amount} eyes"


class Animal(Legs, Eyes):
    def __init__(self, name, legs_amount, eyes_amount):
        self.name = name
        Legs.__init__(self, legs_amount)  
        Eyes.__init__(self, eyes_amount)  

    def legsInfo(self):
        return super().legsInfo()

    def eyesInfo(self):
        return super().eyesInfo()


# Objects
cat = Animal("Tom", 4, 2)  
spider = Animal("Webster", 8, 6) 

# Test de output
print(cat.legsInfo())     # 2 legs ERROR
print(cat.eyesInfo())     # 2 eyes
print(spider.legsInfo())  # 6 legs ERROR
print(spider.eyesInfo())  # 6 eyes

It appears that because of the property amount is used in both classes, this value is shared. Which I think is very strange, it are different classes, so there is no need to share.
Is this a Python bug or some kind of "special feature"?
I have changed the name amount to legsAmount and eyesAmount and then it works fine. I want to define / specify / set the amount variable as "only for this class" or something.

What do you expect the value of cat.amount to be? The pattern you are looking for here is not inheritance but composition. Inheritance means is-a so in your code, an Animal is a Legs (and an Eyes).

I want as a result: cat -> 4 legs and 2 eyes and a spider -> 8 legs and 6 eyes. This as I specify when creating the objects.

Composition is a design principle where one class contains instances of other classes. That is not the case here.

You can make amount "private" with two leading underscores: calling it self.__amount will trigger name mangling in Python, thus giving internally different names to the corresponding class fields of the two classes, and providing the correct output (4 legs 2 eyes 8 legs 6 eyes).

An Animal isn't a Legs, an Animal isn't an Eyes. Child instances are also their parents, in the sense that you can substitute an instance of a child class anywhere you'd use the parent class. The inheritance hierarchy doesn't make sense to begin with.

The answer that Simon describes is correct. What I Learnt: When you are inheriting multiple classes, the properties of these classes are by default shared when they have the same name.
By making them private you get separate properties for all classes.

@Vincent I should have added to my comment: While it might provide a technical solution to your question, I agree with others that your particular example does not appear to be a good use case to be modeled via inheritance.

You can create instances of Legs and Eyes for the animals.
Something like this:
class Legs:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount  

    def legsInfo(self):
        return f"{self.amount} legs"


class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount  

    def eyesInfo(self):
        return f"{self.amount} eyes"


class Animal(Legs, Eyes):
    def __init__(self, name, legs_amount, eyes_amount):
        self.name = name
        self.legs = Legs(legs_amount)  
        self.eyes = Eyes(eyes_amount)  

    def legsInfo(self):
        return self.legs.legsInfo()

    def eyesInfo(self):
        return self.eyes.eyesInfo()


# Objects
cat = Animal("Tom", 4, 2)  
spider = Animal("Webster", 8, 6) 

# Test de output
print(cat.legsInfo())     # 4 legs 
print(cat.eyesInfo())     # 2 eyes
print(spider.legsInfo())  # 8 legs
print(spider.eyesInfo())  # 6 eyes


Correct but in this case, there is no more reason to inherit Animal from Legs and Eyes.

So this solution is no composition and no inheritance. It is just plain OO development, which is good. But not what I'm looking for.

It could help if you understand what a class attribute named with a preceding double underscore will do. The actual variable name is (kind of) obfuscated in that the internal name includes the class name. In that way you can distinguish between variable names that are otherwise identical in multiple inheritance.
Whilst your model may not make much sense, this is one way to overcome your problem:
class Legs:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.__amount = amount
    @property
    def legs(self):
        return self.__amount

class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.__amount = amount
    @property
    def eyes(self):
        return self.__amount

class Animal(Legs, Eyes):
    def __init__(self, name, legsAmount, eyesAmount):
        Legs.__init__(self, legsAmount)
        Eyes.__init__(self, eyesAmount)
        self._name = name
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Name={self.name}, Legs={self.legs}, Eyes={self.eyes}"
        

cat = Animal("cat", 4, 2)
spider = Animal("spider", 8, 6)

print(cat)
print(spider)

Output:
Name=cat, Legs=4, Eyes=2
Name=spider, Legs=8, Eyes=6

You can observe what's happened internally in this example with:
print(cat.__dict__)

...which will emit:
{'_Legs__amount': 4, '_Eyes__amount': 2, '_name': 'cat'}


The answer that Simon provided is right.
What I Learnt: When you are inheriting multiple classes, the properties of these classes are by default shared when, they have the same name. By making them private you get separate properties for all classes
class Legs:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.__amount = amount  

    def legsInfo(self):
        return str(self.__amount) + " poten"

class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.__amount = amount  

    def eyesInfo(self):
        return str(self.__amount) + " ogen"

class Animal(Legs, Eyes):
    def __init__(self, name, legs, eyes):
        self.name = name
        Legs.__init__(self, legs)  
        Eyes.__init__(self, eyes)  

Opinion: I think it is very strange that when you  inherit multiple classes at the same time, the properties of these classes are shared when they have the same name. In my opinion it is a design flaw in Python.

"By making them private you get separate properties for all classes" this is incorrect; you still get shared properties for the Animal class. However, by making it a class-private attribute (prefixing __) then Python renames the attributes to _Legs__amount and _Eyes__amount so that there are two different attributes with distinct names that the owning parent classes can refer to as just __amount.

You mentioned that you'd like to utilize the super() function. But what is the reason?

The conflict is occurring because each class can only have one attribute called amount, so defining it in the Eyes constructor overrides the value from the Legs constructor. The other solutions are fine, but they don't really get to the actual problem: "amount" is a really bad name for an attribute, particularly when there's any possibility of ambiguity. Just give the attribute a different, unambiguous name for the two classes. Don't try to redefine your info methods, either; that kind of kills the point of inheritance.
class Legs:
    def __init__(self, num_legs):
        self.num_legs = num_legs

    def legs_info(self):
        return f"{self.num_legs} legs"

class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, num_eyes):
        self.num_eyes = num_eyes

    def eyes_info(self):
        return f"{self.num_eyes} eyes"


class Animal(Legs, Eyes):
    def __init__(self, name, num_legs, num_eyes):
        self.name = name
        Legs.__init__(self, num_legs)
        Eyes.__init__(self, num_eyes)

dog = Animal("spot", 4, 2)
print(dog.legs_info()) # 4 legs
print(dog.eyes_info()) # 2 eyes



I make 2 animals a cat and a spider. They have a difference number of
legs and eyes. I just want to print these data.

The simpler method to utilize the super() function for minimizing code.
Snippet:
class Mammal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs, eyes):
        self.name = name
        self.legs = legs
        self.eyes =eyes

    def amount(self):
        return f'{self.name} has {self.legs} legs and {self.eyes} eyes'


class Animal(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, name, legs, eyes):         
        super().__init__(name , legs, eyes)

     

# Usage
cat = Animal('Tom',4,2)
spider = Animal("Webster", 8, 6)
print(cat.amount())
print(spider.amount())

Output:
Tom has 4 legs and 2 eyes
Webster has 8 legs and 6 eyes

